# How can I split a list of strings by chunks when they have some light markdown attributes, in F#?

Tags: f#, telegram

I have a tool that is using a Telegram chatbot to interact with its users.

Telegram limits the call rate, so I use a queue system that gets flushed at regular intervals.

So, the current code is very basic:

```
// flush the message queue
let flushMessageQueue() =
    if not messageQueue.IsEmpty then       <- messageQueue is a ConcurrentQueue

        // get all the messages
        let messages =
            messageQueue
            |> Seq.unfold(fun q ->
                match q.TryDequeue () with
                | true, m -> Some (m, q)
                | _ -> None)

        // put all the messages in a single string
        let messagesString = String.Join("\n", messages)

        // send the data
        client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, messagesString, ParseMode.Markdown)
        |> Async.AwaitTask
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> ignore
```

this is called at regular interval, while the write is:

````
// broadcast message
let broadcastMessage message =
    messageQueue.Enqueue(message)
    printfn "%s" (message.Replace ("```", String.Empty))
````

But as messages became more complex, two problems came at once:

Part of the output is formatted text with simple markdown:

- Some blocks of lines are wrapped between ``` sections
- There are some ``` sections as well inside some lines
- The text is UTF-8 and uses a bunch of symbols

Some example of text may be:

````
```
this is a group of lines
with one, or many many lines
```
and sometimes there are things ```like this``` as well
````

And... I found out that Telegram limits message size to 4kb as well

So, I thought of two things:

- I can maintain a state with the open / close ``` and pull from a queue, wrap each line in triple back ticks based on the state and push into another queue that will be used to make the 4kb block.
- I can keep taking messages from the re-formatted queue and aggregate them until I reach 4kb, or the end of the queue and loop around.

Is there an elegant way to do this in F#?
I remember seeing a snippet where a collection function was used to aggregate data until a certain size but it looked very inefficient as it was making a collection of line1, line1+line2, line1+line2+line3... and then picking the one with the right size.